# Change order by in partition by clause based on the value

Tags: sql

I have data with columns contractID, typecode, typecodedate. Typecode can be A1,A2,B1,B2 or empty and one contractID can have multiple typecodes. If contract has empty typecode, I need my query to select that regardless of the typecodedate else. If contract does not have empty typecode it should select typecode with latest typecodedate.

| contractID | typecode | typecodedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20135 |  | 20221020 |
| 20135 | A1 | 20221021 |
| 20136 | A2 | 20221022 |
| 20136 | B1 | 20221023 |

Expected:

| contractID | typecode | typecodedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20135 |  | 20221020 |
| 20136 | B1 | 20221023 |

I've tried to use

```
with a as (select 
contractID,
typecode,
typecodedate,
case when typecode = '' then row_number() over (partition by contractID order by typecode asc)
else row_number() over (partition by contractID order by typecodedate desc) end rank
from table)

select * from a where rank=1
```

This works with contractID that don't have '' typecode, but if contractID has '' and value typecode then it returns rank=1 for both rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the *case expression* to the window function to explicitly control the date used for ordering:

```
with a as (
    select 
    contractID,
    typecode,
    typecodedate,
    row_number() over (
      partition by contractID 
      order by case when typecode = '' then '20990101' else typecodedate end desc
    ) rank
    from table 
)
select * from a 
where rank = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This almost works but I noticed that in case of contract receiving empty typecode for multiple dates, it selects row with earliest date. I need the query to select row with latest date. Would you have suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you need an additional tie-breaker ordering clause, perhaps also add `..., type typecodedate desc` as a second ordering column in the `over order by`